# ASP.net core, whats better and faster, jquery or razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to do my first project in ASP.NET and I decided to render data from Class "Calendar" via razor. It's a static Class desired to handle only one object with static arrays like days and monthsNames etc. But does it mean, all of this is processed on server? Won't it be better to render this via jquery (client side[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8f9Q.png))?

Comment: I think this is an opinion based question.  If it is about perceived speed or actual speed, there is also the question of caching.  

Both approaches are valid.  Generally I think jquery with an API call is best as you separate the API and the Client, making it much easier to reuse or expand.  You can create lazy loading and animations etc and make the client do most of the work.

A razor page can also be heavily cached and super fast and if you structure things well enough you can reuse the services etc in other places.

This is simple enough that you should try both

Answer (score 2):

As with many things, you have a trade-off of competing interests.  With Razor, yes, you are processing more information on the server, but you will only be serving up the finished HTML over the network.  To use JQuery to accomplish the same, you would have to serialize the entire data model into a Javascript object (which also requires server processing) and then pass all that extra data over the network... if you really need all of the data, then this might not be terrible, but in many cases, you will only wind up displaying a small subset of the data.  In-memory operations are typically much faster and more efficient than passing lots of data over the network to be processed.

For other considerations, recall that some browsers will have JavaScript disabled.  Anything that relies on JavaScript either needs some kind of fallback approach, or may fail for some users.  Also, if there is sensitive information in your model that you don't want to expose to the user, then it is better to process it on the server so that you can reveal only the information that you want the user to see.  If you serialize everything and process it with JQuery, then the user can see everything (even if they have to poke around a bit in the HTML source to find it.)

There is not a single right answer, as it would depend on the use case, but as a rule of thumb, I use Razor when I can to create the initial view, and save JQuery for making changes to the DOM (e.g., hiding a div when the user clicks a little red "X") in order to prevent unnecessary requests to the server.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just wondered if this is a proper way to render a big STATIC data. There's no need to hide anything. Its a content seen by everyone...   Thats why I thought thats a wrong behaviour - it forces to render something on server when it could be easily done it in js or even in pure html. It was just an example.

Comment: If it's really static, you can just hard-code everything and not use either.  The only purpose of using a data model and Razor (or JavaScript) is to interpret data that will change depending on the request.  But, if all your doing is using Razor to put pieces of text into the HTML where they are needed, that doesn't necessarily require any more processing power than serializing the same pieces of text into JSON where the JavaScript can read it.